# Java deserialize Arrays.toString() - human readable serialization - config file

Tags: java, arrays, string, serialization, deserialization

I'm building a configuration file, and I'd like to make it both human readable and simple to process.

I only need to use primitives and arrays of primitives (and strings).

Here's an example

```
ID 100; Links [99, 100, 101]; Options [qwe, asd]
ID 100; Links [99, 100, 101]; Options [asd, zxc]
```

Right now I'm using Arrays.toString() and string concatenation to create the above.

I can split the above string using String.split(), which is still simple enough.

Then I'm left with the [.., ..] strings that I need to"deserialize". Is there a simple and straightforward way to reverse what was created by Arrays.toString()?

Comment: Have you tried using a `java.util.Scanner`? Otherwise I don't know of any _straightforward_ way

Comment: I use a scanner to get one line at a time, then String.split to cut the pieces, than I'd like not to look over every comma separated value of the array, but do something smarter. I'm currently looking at [Arrays.fill()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: `Arrays.fill` fills all array cells with the same value, I'm afraid you have to `split` each comma separated list and convert the values one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned the idea of making my config as a simple text file and went full XML.

I found a nice library, [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), that can generate some verbose but quite readable file.

Example output and code

```
<Person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</Person>
```

PhoneNumber class

```
public class PhoneNumber {

    private int code;
    private String number;

    public PhoneNumber(int code, String number) {
        this.code = code;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PhoneNumber{" + "code=" + code + ", number=" + number + '}';
    }

}
```

Person class

```
public class Person {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private PhoneNumber phone;
    private PhoneNumber fax;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setPhone(PhoneNumber phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setFax(PhoneNumber fax) {
        this.fax = fax;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", phone=" + phone + ", fax=" + fax + '}';
    }

}
```

Runner class

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Runner {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Runner.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver()); // does not require XPP3 library

        // shorten tag names when saved
        xstream.alias(Person.class.getSimpleName(), Person.class);
        xstream.alias(PhoneNumber.class.getSimpleName(), PhoneNumber.class);

        // create object
        Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
        joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
        joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));

        // serialize
        String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);

        // open file
        File configFile = new File("Config.txt");

        // write to file
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(configFile, "UTF-8");) {
            xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
            writer.println(xml);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // read file
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(configFile, "UTF-8");) {
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");
            xml = scanner.next();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // deserialize
        Person newJoe = (Person) xstream.fromXML(xml);

        System.out.println("Does toString return the same String? " + joe.toString().equals(newJoe.toString()));
    }
}
```